# constrained optimization ; how to incorporate a constraint

Tags: optimization, constraints

I am solving an equation 
$log_2(1+\frac{xh_d p_d}{s})-\gamma x h_{dc} p_d$

s.t

$xp_d h_{dc}<Q$

my $x$ comes out to be $\frac{1}{\gamma h_{dc} p_d}-\frac{s}{h_d p_d}$

but I dont know how to incorporate the condition $xp_d h_dc<Q$ for $x$ i-e 
my question is whether my

$x$ = $\frac{1}{\gamma h_{dc} p_d}-\frac{s}{h_d p_d}$  $\quad \quad$   $xp_d h_{dc}<Q$

or

$x=\frac{1}{\gamma h_{dc}^2 p_d^2}-\frac{s}{h_d p_d^2 h_{dc}} \quad\quad xp_d h_dc<Q $
( i have divided it by $p_d h_{dc})$

Comment: I see not an equation!

Comment: @ Dr.Sonnhard Graubner I have edited my question now .